# IndexedDB Read From "Value" object - JSON stored + needs to be retrieved

Tags: javascript, html, json, datastore, indexeddb

I am new to IndexedDB and have so far stored a JSON string in the value part of the data store.

I stored this like so:

```
function createDB() {
customerData = [];
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    customerData.push({ id: i, add1: "add1_" + i, add2: "add2_" + i, custName: "ted_" + i });
}
var request = window.indexedDB.open("Customer", 1);

request.onsuccess = function (e) {

    request = e.target.result;
    alert("database created");
};

request.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    var store = db.createObjectStore("cust", { keyPath: "id" });
    var jsonIndex = store.createIndex("by_key", "id", { unique: true });

    var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(customerData);
    var request = store.put({ id: "1", json: jsonStr });
};

};
```

Can anyone tell me how to decode this JSON and read it onto the HTML page?

Comment: hi there, alecf has the correct answer, please mark the question as accepted if it solves your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify the object - IndexedDB can handle that for you:

```
var request = store.put({ id: "1", data: customerData });
```

Also, you don't need to create an index on "id" if your object store already has a keyPath of "id" - you're just creating a duplicate index of the same data.

You can get it by just get()'ing it by id from the objectStore:

```
var request = store.get("1").onsuccess = function(event) {
    var value = event.target.result;
    var customerData = value.data;
}
```

But actually you can simplify this quite a bit because IndexedDB understands numbers and other simple key values:

```
var request = store.put(customerData, 1);
```

and

```
var request = store.get(1).onsuccess = function(event) {
    var customerData = event.target.result;
}
```